# Beating binary search using CPU cache line

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, binary-search, cpu-cache

For educational purposes, I am trying to beat `binary search` using CPU cache line.

https://github.com/nmmmnu/beating_binsearch/blob/master/improved.h

If you uncomment `#define EXIT_ONLY`, the search works like normal `binary search`, except if there are few elements, the search became `linear search`.

As expected this performs **faster** than `binary search`.

However I want to improve future, so if you comment `#define EXIT_ONLY`, then "small" `linear search` is made instead of accessing just the "middle" element.

In theory the values for linear search must be in CPU cache line and access must be "free of charge".

However in practice this search is way too slow than the normal `binary search`.

If I hardcode `CACHE_COUNT_2` to be equal to 1, then speed is comparable, but still slower.

Note I never tried to unroll the for cycle in `_linear()`.

What could be explanation of the slower execution?

Repo with all files is here:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/beating_binsearch

Comment: I think you might get better answers in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2079303 you might, but the question would have to be completely re-done first. Questions on CodeReview need to be **a)** already working as intended and **b)** have the code embedded in the question. In addition, Feature Requests and code explanations are also off-topic.

Comment: i thought about it, but in general everything is only in `improved.h` file. other files are measurement and is not that important how are they written.

Comment: I don't think you will get many answers if you just include a link to your repo instead of inlining the relevant excerpt in your question.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the idea of how adding small searches in the middle should improve the speed. What's the point of doing a small linear search in the middle? It makes sense when you are close to the target, but in all other cases it's pointless spending of virtually free cycles. Let's say the first comparison tells you that you need to go to the left of the middle. What's the point of doing a linear search to the right of the middle?

Comment: If feasible one could try to order the data in a B-tree, that way you can do more reduction (to 25% instead of 50%) of the search space from one cache-line.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - when you check middle element, several addresses after the middle element are load in L1 cache (at least I suppose they are).  
So checking those additional elements is almost free - isn't it?  
If is free, why not doing so, and with this check we are narrowing the remaining "unchecked" space by several elements each time.

Comment: @Nick What if the comparison to midpoint tells you that you need to go below? All the searching to the right of midpoint becomes a perfect waste in this case, because it does not shrink the remaining search space. On top of that, how much saving are you planning to get from searching, say, 8 additional elements? Suppose you've got 20,000,000 elements to search, so your binary search goes for 25 steps. Each step saves you 8 comparisons, so the timing should be similar to searching 19,999,800 elements - a 0.001% improvement.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well, replacing last few bin search "iterations" with linear search, really improves the overall performance. Also by checking 8 elements instead of just one, improving the change for hit "target" element 8 times? (All this is for education of course)

Comment: I would expect a prefetcher to understand binary search and mostly eliminate cache misses. Binary search is not as cache-unfriendly as it looks.

Comment: @nwp, i wouldn't - there's no clear stride or recurring pattern there, even the directions vary randomly (data dependent). You'd need to write some dedicated HW do detect this case and get any real benefit here, and I can't see how this is justified for a single use case.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in your code.  For example, this code does not consider cache line boundaries.

```
while (end - start > CACHE_COUNT_MIN){
//  uint64_t mid = start + ((end - start) /  2);
uint64_t mid = start + ((end - start) >> 1);
```

etc...

```
char cmp = _linear(mid - CACHE_COUNT_2, mid + CACHE_COUNT_2, data, key, mid);
```

Cache lines are allocated on addresses modulo the line size.  So, to scan an entire cache line you would want to mask out the relevant bits of the address.  Even if it is a cache hit though, you will still spend cycles accessing the line (more the higher it is in the hierarchy).

Binary search is already one of the more cache efficient algorithms for comparison based search though so improving it through cache awareness may be difficult.  You eliminate half the search space at each iteration, which already avoids most cache misses, and it's a linear space, and you increase locality with each search.  Prediction can even hide some of the misses.

You may want to use [`perf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_%28Linux%29) to sample performance events in your code.  Also, to get an idea of how cache awareness is sometimes used to optimize algorithms, you might also want to take a look at some of the existing aware ones like [hopscotch hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing).

Comment: "Cache lines are allocated on addresses modulo the line size" - I do not clearly understand this, can you elaborate about it please and probably give me some simple code

Comment: The starting address of a cache line can never be anything other than a multiple of the line size.  So, the starting address is always of the form `(line_size x n)`.  What that means is that you can mask out the relevant bits to get the starting address of a cache line (e.g. `(line_size >> 3) - 1`.

Comment: so for 64 bytes cache line, in order to find beginning of the line, i need to "clear" 6 least significant bits, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, six bits (`line_size - 1`).  Sorry, ignore above.

Comment: @Nick Here's a [link](http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/) to an article that goes into a bit more depth on optimizing cache alignment.

Answer (score 2):

I did unrolled version of the search,

https://github.com/nmmmnu/beating_binsearch/blob/master/improved_unroll.h

here is code in question:

```
char search(uint64_t const start1, uint64_t const end1, const T *data, const T key, uint64_t &index) const{
    /*
     * Lazy based from Linux kernel...
     * http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bsearch.c
     */

    uint64_t start = start1;
    uint64_t end   = end1;

    char cmp = 0;

    //while (start < end){
    while (start < end){
    //  uint64_t mid = start + ((end - start) /  2);
        uint64_t mid = start + ((end - start) >> 1);

        //char cmp = _linear(mid - CACHE_COUNT_2, mid + CACHE_COUNT_2, data, key, mid);

        #define _LINE_HALF_SIZE 7
        #define _LINE(i)                        \
        if (i >= end){                          \
            start = mid + _LINE_HALF_SIZE + 1;  \
            continue;                           \
        }                                       \
                                                \
        cmp = comp.cmp(data[i], key);           \
                                                \
        if (cmp == 0){                          \
            index = i;                          \
            return 0;                           \
        }                                       \
                                                \
        if (cmp > 0){                           \
            end = i + 1;                        \
            continue;                           \
        }

        _LINE(mid - 7);
        _LINE(mid - 6);
        _LINE(mid - 5);
        _LINE(mid - 4);
        _LINE(mid - 3);
        _LINE(mid - 2);
        _LINE(mid - 1);
        _LINE(mid    );
        _LINE(mid + 1);
        _LINE(mid + 2);
        _LINE(mid + 3);
        _LINE(mid + 4);
        _LINE(mid + 5);
        _LINE(mid + 6);
        _LINE(mid + 7);

        #undef _LINE

        start = mid + _LINE_HALF_SIZE + 1;
    }

    index = start;
    return cmp;
}
```

Seems there are too many branch miss-predictions, because if I remove following `if` statement:

```
        if (i >= end){                          \
            start = mid + _LINE_HALF_SIZE + 1;  \
            continue;                           \
        }                                       \
```

speed "magically" became same or even better than `classical binary search` - of course, because I eliminated the branch the algorithm did not really worked correctly, but this is clear indication why the algorithm is slower than `classical binary search`.